# Call plugin-defined function in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, git, plugin-vim-plug, plugin-fugitive

I use [tpope/vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) and [airblade/vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) and I want to selectively enable gitgutter only in git repositories.

Since `vim-fugitive` provides `FugitiveIsGitDir` which returns `0` or `1`, this could be achieved as such (snippet from `.vimrc`):

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'

call plug#end()

let g:gitgutter_enabled = FugitiveIsGitDir()
```

However, I am getting

```
E117: Unknown function: FugitiveIsGitDir
```

since the plugin files of `vim-fugitive` are sourced **after** that line is executed. Here's an excerpt from `:scriptnames`:

```
  1: /etc/xdg/nvim/sysinit.vim
  2: /usr/share/nvim/archlinux.vim

  " here's where I define 
  " let g:gitgutter_enabled = FugitiveIsGitDir()
  3: ~/.config/nvim/init.vim

  4: ~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim
  5: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.vim

  8: ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-fugitive/ftdetect/fugitive.vim
 
  " here's where FugitiveIsGitDir is sourced
 20: ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim
```

---

My question is: can I somehow make use of `FugitiveIsGitDir()` in this case? Maybe forcefully loading `vim-fugitive` earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
# vimrc
autocmd BufEnter * if FugitiveIsGitDir() | GitGutterBufferEnable | else | GitGutterBufferDisable | endif
```

However I'm curious why you need to turn off gitgutter in non-git directories.  There shouldn't be overhead to having it there.

Answer (score 5):

All directories in your Vim runtimepath can have a directory called `after` which can contain directories like `plugin` and `ftplugin` but get sourced after the regular ol' `plugin` and `ftplugin` directories are sourced.

```
# ~/.vim/after/plugin/enable_git_gutter.vim
let g:gitgutter_enabled = FugitiveIsGitDir()
```

See `:help after-directory` for more.

Comment: While it may work, I find changing a global option that is likely to be read when the plugin is started quite fishy. Instead, it's likely better (from an after plugin file) to execute a command or a function, instead of setting a `enable` global variable too late (as the plugin as already started doing its stuff).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `:h starting`, you'll see that plugin files are sourced after `.vimrc` is entirely processed.

Functions defined in autoload plugin files could be used directly as long as the `'runtimepath'` option as been updated (by plugin managers). However if you need to use a function defined in a plugin file, then you'll need to source that file explicitly as you've guessed.